# No Sound is being played even though its not throwing error

Tags: java, audio

So I have constructed this code below. It is part of an alarm clock system and I want it to play an alarm clock sound when the ints set match the current time. When the code is ran it just doesn't play any sound. What could be causing it not to play? Thanks.

```
Timer alarmCheck = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(alarmHour == hour)
            {
                if(alarmMin == min)
                {
                    if(sec == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Alert!");

                        try
                        {
                            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/Alarm Clock.wav"));
                            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            clip.open(audioIn);
                            clip.start();
                        }
                        catch(Exception a)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Error Playing Sound");
                            a.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you certain your code is reaching the sound part?

Comment: So the "Alert!" String is in fact posted?

Comment: Ahh Sorry, yes it does reach the System.out and does print Alert

Comment: I have just placed print statements in between each line within the try block and it reaches clip.start();

Comment: ... and no exceptions are produced? ... and you're sure that the sound file is valid, that it works, that your computer's sound is on? Is this code being run from a jar file, and thus, do you need to use resources instead of files? As an aside, the sound should be played from within a background thread, but this is not the cause of your current problem, only your next problem.

Comment: No exceptions are being produced and I am running this from within Eclipse, so a .class

Comment: Sorry didn't see your edited post. Yes the sound file works and computer sound is on

Comment: Try adding `System.out.printf("file size=%,d%n", new File("src/Alarm Clock.wav").length());` right after the System.out.println("Alert!") line.  Does it print a number larger than zero?

Comment: So declared AlarmBell as a file with path src/ Alarm Clock.wav and did System.out.println(AlarmBell.length()); and it returned 6116134